# Update SharePoint Online item build-in fields via Microsoft Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, flow, update

Is it possible to update SharePoint Online build-in fields (like "Created by") by using Microsoft Flow?

When creating a new flow and using step "Update file properties", I can only select values to be updated for Title and newly created custom fields, but there are no possibilities to update built-in fields. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the Author (Created By) or another field by using REST API `_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<list>')/items(<item id>)` and send `POST` request in the flow.

For example:

[image]

Note:

By default, the Author is read-only field. You need to change the attribute `ReadOnlyField` to `false` for this field. You can post to: `/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('<list>')/Fields('<fieldguid>')` and update the field `ReadOnlyField` to `false`. After that, the field value can be editable.

Comment: Thank You - I will definitely try this approach.

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cx7P.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cx7P.png)Thank you for this solution. I am try to edit the "Modified By" column with the approver's name but my screen doesn't seem to look like yours. I am adding it as an step to my current flow.