# Have the Approver show as the modified person in Flow/PowerAutomate

Tags: flow, power-automate

Currently I have a flow running but the Modified column only show my name because I am the flow creator.  I want it to update with the approver's name instead.

I tried to use HTTP Request to SharePoint but my screen does not look the same as the solution shown here: [Update SharePoint Online item build-in fields via Microsoft Flow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/259634/update-sharepoint-online-item-build-in-fields-via-microsoft-flow/274593?noredirect=1#comment291758_274593).  Can the experts give me some guidelines on how to accomplish this?

This is what my HTTP request screen look like[image]:

Comment: The only difference I see in your screenshot is that you don't have the same Headers, which you would have to manually type in.  Once you add `content-type` in the "Enter Key" field, it will give you another row to enter "IF-MATCH" and so on...

Comment: Also, you probably don't want to hardcode "11", this is the ID of a specific user, you would need to get the ID of the approver to pass "'EditorId': approverid".

Comment: Thanks!  I got that now.  If my Document Library name is WF%20Vendor  do I put this for the body?

  {'_metadata':{'type':'SP.Data.Vendor%20VendorListItem'},'EditorID':[Approval ID]}

Comment: It should be SP.Data.{contentTypeName}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to recap the conversation from the above comments:

In order to use the extend `metadata` object in a REST JSON POST update to existing Item, the following headers need to be set (this applies whether calling from a Power Automate Flow or some other REST-connected solution):

content-type:  application/json;odata=verbose
if-match: *
x-http-method: MERGE

In addition, the `type` specified within the `metadata` object should be the name of the ContentType of the item you are attempting to update.

Comment: So if Document is the content type then type should be {'_metadata':{'type':'SP.Data.Document'},'EditorID':ApprovalID}

Comment: Yes, if using the built-in Document content type.

Comment: Tried it and got the error:  Invalid JSON. A comma character ',' was expected in scope 'Object'. Every two elements in an array and properties of an object must be separated by commas.

Comment: Can you post your whole jSON?  That sounds like there is just an mistyped character somewhere

Comment: `Uri:  _api/web/lists/GetByTitle('WF Vendor')/items(@{triggerBody()?['ID']})`


`content-type: application/json;odata=verbose`


`body: {'_metadata':{'type':'SP.Data.Document'},'EditorID':@{body('Start_and_wait_for_an_approval')?['name']}}`

Comment: I don't think the `name` property is what you want to pass, `name` is going to be a string value, which would need to be wrapped in single quotes, but I think `EditorID` is expecting a number, does the `wait_for_approval` give you the approver user's ID?

Comment: I think you are right.  It's giving me this as the ID `a268f37c-2197-43bf-bbbb-a75e994ad962`

Comment: Assuming your approval one has one responder, you should be able to get it by replacing your current `EditorID` JSON with `'EditorID':@{first(body('Start_and_wait_for_an_approval')?['responses'])['responder']?['id']}`

Comment: I did that `{'_metadata':{'type':SP.Data.Document'},'EditorID':de21aee0-8f4d-4674-a1ba-480401048eeb}`  but got this error now `Invalid JSON. A token was not recognized in the JSON content.\r\nclientRequestId: 1cd4e405-62fc-49a4-b7cd-e45adedc1ccc\r\nserviceRequestId: 97072e9f-604c-0000-41fc-0300fa002aea`

Comment: If the value you are passing in JSON is not a numeric value, then it has to be enclosed in quotes (even if that value is dynamically coming from another Flow Step:  'EditorID':'@{first(body('Start_and_wait_for_an_approval')?['responses'])['responder']?['id']}'  Although, I am pretty sure that the EditorID expects a numeric ID, so we still need to figure out how to translate that GUID in SharePoint's UserID

Comment: Assuming that even wrapping the guid in quotes doesn't help, try adding a 'Compose' step and set it equal to the entire body('Start_and_wait_for_an_approval').  That way when you view the failed workflow we can examine the entire JSON response coming from the approval to see if that numeric ID that we need is in there somewhere.